# NULL POINTER EXCEPTION when I try to add a player? in JAVA

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception, null

so i'm trying to pass an initialized object which is "p" from one file to method add() in another file. Null exception occurs at storage[count]=p

```
public class PlayerList {
private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 2;

private Player[] storage;
private int count;

public PlayerList() {
    // Initialize the storage array and set count to 0.
        Player[] storage = new Player[2];
        storage[0] = new Player("default name1");           
        storage[1] = new Player("default name2");    
        count = 0;
}
public void add(Player p) {
    storage[count] = p;         
    count++;
}
```

---

```
//In another file:
public static void PlayerListTestOne() {
    System.out.println("PlayerList testing: constructor, size, add, get(0), find");

    PlayerList l = new PlayerList();
    Player p = new Player("Derek Jeter");

    displayResults(l.size() == 0);
    l.add(p);
    displayResults(l.size() == 1);
    displayResults(l.get(0).equals(p));
    displayResults(l.find(p) != -1);
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that this is C++?

Comment: You are shadowing your field variable. You declare a new `Player[] player` local variable in your constructor, and you are initializing that rather than the field.

Comment: Update: I moved  Player[] storage = new Player[2]; from inside the constructor to outside as a global. Error is gone! Why?

Comment: Vince Emigh already explained above. If you want to work the old way replace the first code line in constructor by this.storage = new Player[2];

Comment: awesome. thanks guys